# Remove everything after a 10 digit number regex

Tags: regex

I have millions of lines like the one below:

```
0032       0001        0020413300               0001           BLUE OVERCOAT               CC                 P
```

I managed to remove the text before by using:

```
.*(?=\d{10})
```

To remove everything *after* I'm trying this:

```
\d{10}.*
```

But it's selecting the number & everything after. How can I leave the number and select everything after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a capturing group:

```
(\d{10}).*
```

and replace with `$1`. See [**the regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/9u2mwi/1).

Also consider using word boundaries to match 10-digit number as a whole word:

```
\b(\d{10})\b.*
```

See [**another regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/1GOrD6/1).

If you are working in Notepad++, you may use `\K` that will drop the matched text up its position: `\b\d{10}\b\K.*` and replace with an empty string. Or a lookbehind: `(?<=\b\d{10}\b).*`.

See [yet another demo](https://regex101.com/r/1GOrD6/2).

Comment: That *still* selects the number as well, I need to keep the number. Edit: K.* works, thanks.

Comment: All the solutions will keep the number. Demos added to the answer.

Comment: you could match all (after and before group) with .*(\d{10}).* and replace by $1.

Comment: @mquantin: That will keep lines that have no 10-digit number. If the task is to remove all but 10-digit numbers, I would suggest another solution (especially if it is for Notepad++).